# Como conectar uma aplicação Java ao Mysql-in App no Azure?

Tags: java, mysql, microsoft-azure, cloud

Como conectar uma aplicação via url ao banco Mysql(Myslq-inApp) dentro do azure ?

```
        String urlLOCAL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crudjsp";
        String urlAzure = "jdbc:";


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlLOCAL,"root","");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conexão no banco MySql-InApp no azure é muito semelhante a conexão local do servidor Xampp. Bastando setar as variáveis de user: "azure", password:"senhaDositema" e host:"local" para realizar a conexão. Meu código ficou assim:

```
String user = "azure";
String password = "6#vWHD_$";

String urlAzure= "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:54447/localdb";    
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlAzure,user,password);      
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
```

Resposta obtida apartir deste post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601885/azure-where-is-default-user-pass-for-wordpress-database-using-mysql-in-appprev